# Ubuntu 12.04 Tenda W322p

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I had a fully operational version of Ubuntu 11.10 running (64 bit) and decided to upgrade to 12.04.  After I did I no longer had network connectivity.  I am running a Tenda Wireless W322P adapter.  In the past I had installed it just fine and it was working great.  Everytime I did a kernel update I would always have to do a

```
modprobe rt3562sta
```

to reinstall and get the network working.  Now, I do that and I get the error

```
FATAL: Error inserting rt3562sta (/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt3562sta.ko): Invalid module format
```

I am dead in the water.  Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer that helps the most so that other users can find it and know it works with a quick glance. Use the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the answer given and it didn't work. It compiled and was properly installed, but no network.

You can go into `os/linux/makefile.cfg` and set the options:

```
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y  
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

Recompile, and reboot.

It should now work.

Comment: There is no `makefile.cfg` in the `os/linux/` subdirectory....